# HTA Access for URLs to remove trailing slash with parameters

Tags: .htaccess

Have an old Java webservice that I was hoping to port into a PHP / Apache web service

https://mylink.com/app/AppServlet?parameters

However in Apache the URL resolves with a trailing slash which Chrome reads as insecure.
https://mylink.com/app/AppServlet/?parameters

I am trying to resolve for:
https://mylink.com/app/AppServlet?parameters

One workaround I was trying was create AppServlet.php inside of the "app/" folder and then somehow use HTACCESS to remove the PHP and still render the content securely without the .PHP or trailing slash before parameters?
https://mylink.com/app/AppServlet?parameters

I tried a number of combinations of HTA Access this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /license/$1.php/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Think I figured it out. Inside of app folder I created an AppServlet.php and then with this HTACCESS it removes the PHP.
```
RewriteRule license/(.*)$ app/AppServlet.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
````

Comment: "in Apache the URL resolves with a trailing slash" - What do you mean by that? Do you mean there is a redirect to append the slash? Is `/app/AppServlet` a physical directory? "which Chrome reads as insecure" - What do you mean by "insecure"? I can't see why Chrome would see this any differently in regards to "security"? The directive in your comment would only seem relevant if you change the URL - where does `license` come from? "HTA Access"?